# How do I increase braking power and "touchiness" of Sram Guide RS Brakes?

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, sram

I've got some Sram Guide RS disk brakes and they're very weak and not touchy at all. I prefer touchy brakes. I know the Guide RSC has the tool free contact adjustment to make them touchier. I have heard the RS can be changed with a tool but can't figure out how. Does anyone know?

Comment: Did you bed the brakes in?  That can increase the power.  There are instructions here: https://sram-cdn-pull-zone-gsdesign.netdna-ssl.com/cdn/farfuture/BGggUd-hAFTXsUZ8rIsl5HQJjqFw14umUC83Ejuw2GI/mtime:1444836523/sites/default/files/techdocs/95-5018-012-000_rev_d_guide_rsc_rs_r_db5_bleed.pdf (near the end)

Comment: @brendan yeah I bled the brakes in so its weird! It's not actually the pads though, it's more the lever I think. They nearly reach the handlebar before locking up.

Comment: I don't think anyone knows what you mean by touchy. Try to rephrase using modulation. http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/11282/what-does-modulate-mean-when-referring-to-brakes

Comment: My guess is that you need to bleed your brakes again or you have a leak somewhere, based on how the lever is behaving. Also, bedding and bleeding aren't the same thing -- bedding puts a layer of brake pad material on the rotors so they work better. Bleeding gets rid of air in a hydraulic system.

Answer (score 2):

Are they new brakes that you installed or you've had them for a bit and this is a new development? It sounds like they need to be properly bled, with that much lever pull your not getting the pressure that you should be. There could be a leak in the system or if you bled them yourself may not have got all of the air out.

I own the RSC's and their awesome, I have also heard very good things about the RS as well so you should be having no problem with them from a braking standpoint.

Although the "touchiness" you seek may have some to do with the brand. I much prefer Sram over Shimano but many do not. Shimano has what some refer to as an on/off feel meaning they either bite or don't. Sram has a much better modulation where the brakes ease into the slow down rather than just locking up the wheel.

Also if the pads were contaminated or not properly bedded then it could be the issue but it sounds like you have air in the lines still. Guides are typically pretty easy to bleed compared to some others.