# Shimano integrated shifter/brake: Cantilever compatible with V-Brake?

Tags: brakes, replacement

I have to replace an integrated shifter/brake, right side, 7 speed Shimano STX.

Is a shifter for V-brake (e.g., [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-Shimano-Deore-XT-ST-M091-STI-3X7-SP-Shifter-Brake-Levers-/331736780342)) compatible?

[Bobotech recommends here](http://www.bikeforums.net/bicycle-mechanics/820126-sti-slr-shifters.html) not to do such replacement.

This question is related to my [broken shifter spring](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36577/shimano-stx-rear-shifter-broken-spring) one

Comment: No, the amount of brake cable pulled by the two levers is different. See [questions like this one](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/why-dont-road-bikes-use-v-brakes) that mention it. I used a search for [cantilever v brake](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=cantilever+v+brake) to find that. There are better explanations on the site I'm sure, but that's the one I found easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally road caliper and cantilever brakes are not compatible with "V"  brakes levers. You have a few basic options. Find a single shifter and reuse your brake lever, find an integrated shifter for canti brakes,( likely a rare find), up grade your brake to a "V" brake. Your local shop may help with some used parts. In my area used brakes go for around $10. This is for arms, pads and a cable noodle. You should see an improvement in braking with the "V" brakes.

Comment: Reusing the brake lever and getting only a shifter sounds interesting. Would I have to remove the old shifter part? I am not sure if would be able to separate brake lever from shifter. And if not, another shifter would probably not fit... I do not have the bike with me now.

Comment: Clarification: Find a non integrated shifter ( shifter and brake lever are separate components) and use the cantilever brake lever that came with the bike, Use the integrated shifter and upgrade the brakes to "V" brakes.